# Is it possible to fetch a HTML select with a Serveur File through jersey?

Tags: java, html, jersey

I am coding a webservice with jersey and maven in java and i am trying to dynamicly fetch a HTML select from my jsp using a json doc located on my server.

I was only wondering if ever it is possible to simply extract or communicate the data from this json file (which is in my main.resources) and to fetch my select with it using java or jersey or smt

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: i've heard using jquerry to get the json but i am very new to web programmation